# random byte to int java

Tags: java, random, byte, bitwise-operators, twos-complement

3. In the Random class, define a nextByte method that returns a value of the primitive type
   byte. The values returned in a sequence of calls should be uniformly distributed over all the
   possible values in the type.
4. In the Random class, define a nextInt method that returns a value of the primitive type
   int. The values returned in a sequence of calls should be uniformly distributed over all the possible
   values in the type.
   (Hint: Java requires implementations to use the twos-complement representation for integers.
   Figure out how to calculate a random twos-complement representation from four random byte
   values using Java’s shift operators.)

Hi I was able to do part 3 and now I need to use 3. to solve 4. but I do not know what to do. I was thinking of using nextByte to make an array of 4 bytes then would I take twos complement of each so I wouldn't have negative numbers and then I would put them together into one int.
byte[] bytes = {42,-15,-7, 8} Suppose nextByte returns this bytes.
Then I would take the twos complement of each which i think would be {42, 241, 249, 8}. Is this what it would look like and why doesn't this code work:

```
public static int twosComplement(int input_value, int num_bits){
    int mask = (int) Math.pow(2, (num_bits - 1));
    return -(input_value & mask) + (input_value & ~mask);
  }
```

Then I would use the following to put all four bytes into an int, would this work:

```
int i= (bytes[0]<<24)&0xff000000|
       (bytes[1]<<16)&0x00ff0000|
       (bytes[2]<< 8)&0x0000ff00|
       (bytes[3]<< 0)&0x000000ff;
```

Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Just take the four random bytes and combine them as in your last statement. Get rid of the twosComplement method, it's just a complicated NO-OP.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment says that Java *already* uses two's complement integers. This is a useful property that simplifies the rest of the code: it guarantees that if you group together 32 random bits (or in general however many bits your desired output type has), then this covers all possible values exactly once and there are no invalid patterns.

That might not be true of some other integer representations, which might only have 2³²-1 different values (leaving an invalid pattern that you would have to avoid) or have 2³² valid patterns but both a "positive" and a "negative" zero, which would cause a random bit pattern to have a biased "interpreted value" (with zero occurring twice as often as it should).

So that it not something for you to do, it is a convenient property for you to use to keep the code simple. Actually you already used it. This code:

```
int i= (bytes[0]<<24)&0xff000000|
       (bytes[1]<<16)&0x00ff0000|
       (bytes[2]<< 8)&0x0000ff00|
       (bytes[3]<< 0)&0x000000ff;
```

Works properly thanks to those properties. By the way it can be simplified a bit: after shifting left by 24, there is no more issue with sign-extension, all the extended bits have been shifted out. And shifting left by 0 is obviously a no-op. So `(bytes[0]<<24)&0xff000000` can be written as `(bytes[0]<<24)`, and `(bytes[3]<< 0)&0x000000ff` as `bytes[3]&0xff`. But you can keep it as it was, with the nice regular structure.
The `twosComplement` function is not necessary.